# Angular HTTP client GeoServer REST API mapping

Tags: angular, http, geoserver

I'm using an Angular service to interact with the GeoServer REST API.  The JSON response for getting layers is:

```
{
    "layers": {
        "layer": [
            {
                "name": "facility",
                "href": "http://localhost/geoserver/rest/workspaces/unacorn/layers/facility.json"
            },
            {
                "name": "opensky",
                "href": "http://localhost/geoserver/rest/workspaces/unacorn/layers/opensky.json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My service method is:

```
public getLayers(): Observable<Layer[]> {
    let layerUrl = this.geoUrl + "/rest/workspaces/unacorn/layers";
    
    return this.http.get<Layer[]>(layerUrl, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          return {
            layers: <Layer[]>response.layers.layer
          }
        })
      )
  }
```

***UPDATED 7/7:
The caller code is:

```
ngOnInit() {

  let layers = Layer[];
  
  this.geoService.getLayers().subscribe((response: Layer[]) => {
    if (response) {
      console.log(response.length) // Array length 2
      layers = response;
    }
  });
  console.log(layers.length) // Array length 0
```

In the console, the second log output shows up first, which seems to mean that it is being executed before the subscribe has returned.  I can work around this with scope, but I seem to be missing something fundamental.

END OF UPDATE***

The model for a layer is:

```
export interface Layer {
  name: string
  href: string
}
```

The data is getting returned correctly, but I can't get the mapping to my model to work properly.  This is the error I'm seeing at compile time:

**Type 'Observable<{ data: any; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Layer[]>'.
Type '{ data: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Layer[]': length,pop, push, concat, and 29 more.ts(2322)**

All the docs and posts I've read show casting to the model interface is the correct approach.  I'm likely just missing something simple.  TIA for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that line:

```
return this.http.get<Layer[]>(layerUrl, this.httpOptions)
```

You are writing that the return type from the GET should be *Layer[]* but it is not. It is an Object with a property Layers. The type of GET (value in <>) should be the type that the API returns. To solve the issue, you can create an interface representing the type of the return value.
**Solution:**

```
export interface ApiResponse {
  layers: {
    layer: Layer[]
  }
}

public getLayers(): Observable<Layer[]> {
  let layerUrl = this.geoUrl + "/rest/workspaces/unacorn/layers"; 
  return this.http.get<ApiResponse>(layerUrl, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      map(response => {
        return response.layers.layer;
      })
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the guidance.  As a follow-up, it appears that I also need some async/await/Promise logic to enable my app to wait for the return of this call.  Any additional thoughts there would be appreciated!

Comment: Am I wrong in assuming that subscribing for an Observable, in this case resulting from an HTTP GET, should work synchronously?  It's not working as I have it right now, execution continues without the data from the API call.

Comment: @RichJones I don't understand what your new issue is. When you subscribe, you don't need any async, await or Promise. The observable will work asynchronously. What do you mean with "execution continues without the data from the API call". You can add more info on what you mean in your original question and not in the comments here.

Comment: In my map component, in ngOnInit, I subscribe to the Observable as defined in my service function getLayers().  The response data is received and I verify the array size in the dev tools console.  However, if I assign the response to a function-scoped local variable, then print out that variable, I get a length of 0 of that array.  The assignment is within the subscribe call, so I may be dealing with a scope issue.  I need to populate a widget with the names of the layers received, so do I need to do that within the subscribe scope?

Comment: Please add more code to your question so I can better understand.